# UIButton shadow and lighting effect (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to add a lighting effect like these two buttons, a shadow on the bottom but also a lighted edge on top as if there were a light above it.

[image]

I've been experimenting with :

```
button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
button.layer.shadowColor.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
button.layer.shadowColor.layer.shadowRadius = 2
button.layer.shadowColor.layer.shadowOpacity = 8
button.layer.shadowColor.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

and get a nice shadow on the bottom, but how would I light up the top edge?

Comment: It's simple: you have to _draw_ that effect as part of the background of the button. I would actually suggest drawing both the light shape at the top and the dark shape at the bottom yourself.

Comment: "Simple" for you maybe...  Do you mean just draw two lines, appropriate thickness and color, one on top, one on bottom?

Comment: I mean either draw it beforehand in Photoshop or whatever and use that drawing, or else construct the drawing in code in iOS using Swift by using UIGraphicsImageRenderer and UIBezierPath and CGContext and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a button pretty similar to your first drawing, just as an experiment:

[image]

The button background is constructed entirely using elementary drawing commands involving UIBezierPath and CGContext in a UIGraphicsImageRenderer. So if that's an acceptable sort of approach, you could just do a tweak on the sort of thing I'm doing.

```
let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width:100, height:100))
let im = r.image {
    ctx in let con = ctx.cgContext
    do {
        let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50), cornerRadius: 10)
        UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
        p.fill()
    }
    do {
        let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50), cornerRadius: 10)
        UIColor(white: 0.1, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
        p.fill()
    }
    do {
        let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 2, width: 100, height: 95), cornerRadius: 10)
        p.addClip()
    }
    let locs : [CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.0 ]
    let colors : [CGFloat] = [
        0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 1.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
        0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 1.0,
    ]
    let sp = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let grad = CGGradient(
        colorSpace:sp, colorComponents: colors, locations: locs, count: 4)!
    con.drawLinearGradient(grad,
                           start: CGPoint(x:0,y:0), end: CGPoint(x:0,y:100), options:[])
}
let b = UIButton(type: .custom)
b.setTitle("9", for: .normal)
b.setBackgroundImage(im, for: .normal)
b.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
b.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: .bold)
self.view.addSubview(b)
b.layer.borderWidth = 1
b.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
b.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Comment: Thank you!  Certainly more work than I'd bargained on - I'd hoped there was just a property I had missed.

Comment: I guess what I'm suggesting is that the ability to treat iOS itself as a drawing program _is_ that property. :)